# Removing commented lines of text in a string

Tags: string-manipulation

Suppose that I have a string `str`.  `str` contains headings -- which are written in commented lines -- and data.  For example:

```
str = "# Heading 1
# Heading 2
@ Heading 3
@ Heading 4
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3";
```

where `#` and `@` denote commented lines.

Now, I would like to write a function `removeComments` to remove all lines in `str` that are commented.  That is, I would like to remove all lines in `str` that start with the character `#` or the character `@`.

I have come up with one way to do this, I think.  My procedure is to first split `str` into lines using `StringSplit` with the `"\n"` delimiter; then use `DeleteCases` to delete all lines in that list which begin with either `#` or `@`; and, finally, convert the list back to a string using `Riffle` and `StringJoin`.  So, I have the following:

```
removeComments[str_String] := Module[{result},
  result = StringSplit[str, "\n"];
  result = 
   DeleteCases[
    result, _?(StringMatchQ[#, ("#" ~~ ___) | ("@" ~~ ___)] &)];
  result = StringJoin[Riffle[result, "\n"]];
  result
  ]
removeComments[str]
```

which gives the following *correct* output (a string):

```
Data 1
Data 2
Data 3
```

*However*, now suppose that one of my data items (for example, a single space in front of `Data 2`) has one or more leading spaces:

```
str = "# Heading 1
# Heading 2
@ Heading 3
@ Heading 4
Data 1
 Data 2
Data 3";

removeComments[str]
```

In this case, I get the ***incorrect*** output:

```
Data 1
Data 3
```

That is, `Data 2` is omitted altogether.  Something is clearly wrong with my approach, but I haven't been able to find my mistake (although it is probably obvious).  Could you please help me find what is wrong?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you wish to keep the leading space before "Data 2" or do you wish to discard it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Sorry; I was not clear.  I would like to *keep* the leading space before `Data 2`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No problem!  :-)  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Andrew, I notice that you didn't Accept my answer.  Is that an oversight or do you find it lacking?  Can I improve it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry! It was just an oversight on my part; I have used your help but forgot to Accept. Your answer has been extremely helpful to me! Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem; I sincerely wanted to know if there was something that needed improvement.  (I think between the two answers everything is there.)  Thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Corrected answer

My original answer (see edit history) was not correct, unless all of your data lines are contiguous.

```
str = "# Heading 1\n# Heading 2\n@ Heading 3\n@ Heading 4\nData 1\n Data 2\nData 3\n@ \
Heading 5\nData 4";

StringReplace[str, Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ "@" | "#" ~~ ___ ~~ "\n"] :> ""]
```

> ```
> "Data 1\n Data 2\nData 3\nData 4"
> ```

Or:

```
"" <> StringSplit[str, Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ "@" | "#" ~~ ___ ~~ "\n"]]
```

> ```
> "Data 1\n Data 2\nData 3\nData 4"
> ```

And the RE equivalent:

```
First @ StringPattern`PatternConvert[Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ "@" | "#" ~~ ___ ~~ "\n"]]
```

> ```
> "(?ms)^[@#].*?\n"
> ```

```
"" <> StringSplit[str, RegularExpression["(?ms)^[@#].*?\n"]]
```

> ```
> "Data 1\n Data 2\nData 3\nData 4"
> ```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, this works as desired, in that all data is retained (including the leading space before `Data 2`).

Comment: @Andrew Okay, great.  I added the RE equivalent if you enjoy such things.

Comment: Although it hasn't been specified clearly I think it might be more robust to use `___` instead of just `__` to also discard empty comment lines, which otherwise well might cause problems when trying to interpret the remaining lines. The RE equivalent would be `.*` instead of `.+`

Comment: @Albert Good point; I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

This answer only discusses the implied question of why the OP's code fails. I think this should be made clear because it puzzled me until Mr.Wizard and rm -rf enlightened me. I would like keep others from falling into the same trap.

I was studying the code posted in this question, trying to learn why it failed, when I ran into the following.

```
StringMatchQ[" ", "@"]
```

> True

I found this very surprising and posted a question on it for a very short period. Mr.Wizard and rm -rf quickly pointed out that `@` was a wild card character and that my code should be

```
StringMatchQ[" ", "\\@"]
```

> False

This same mistake also occurs in the code posted in the question above. With the following minor change, the OP's code works.

```
removeComments[str_String] := 
  Module[{result},
    result = StringSplit[str, "\n"];
    result = 
      DeleteCases[result, _?(StringMatchQ[#, ("#" ~~ ___) | ("\\@" ~~ ___)] &)];
    StringJoin[Riffle[result, "\n"]]]

removeComments[
  "# Heading 1\n# Heading 2\n@ Heading 3\n@ Heading 4\nData 1\n Data 2\nData 3"]
```

> Data 1
>   $\ $Data 2
>   Data 3

Comment: +1 for providing the other half of the answer; I enjoy problem solving more than debugging so I skipped this (important) part.

Comment: Incidentally the pattern could be condesed like this: `StringMatchQ[#, "#" | "\\@" ~~ ___]`

Comment: What is an rm -rf?

Comment: @Hector. It's a kind of moderator :-)